# HTML PHP Formatting

Tags: php, forms, email

I want to format emails that are sent from a php webform

at the moment they appear like this

---

Name: Justin B

Email: example@mail.com

Phone: 0123456789

IP: (senders ip)

Comments: Hello

---

I'd like the text bigger but if i put thing like `<h2>` in the $email_message section it just outputs  as text not as html.

None of the articles around the web seem to help/work

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
     
 
    $email_to = "example@mail.com";
   
         
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
   
        echo "Please fix errors below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please fix these errors and resubmit form.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
     
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                !isset($_POST['subject'])||
                !isset($_POST['phone'])||
        !isset($_POST['comments']))
               
               
                {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }
     
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
        $subject = $_POST['subject'] ;
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
   
       
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
   
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 
    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name);
    $email_message .= " ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "IP: ".clean_string($ip)."\n";
        $email_message .= "\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
       
 
     
// create email headers
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 
function IsInjected($str)
{
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
           '(\r+)',
           '(\t+)',
           '(%0A+)',
           '(%0D+)',
           '(%08+)',
           '(%09+)'
           );
               
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
     
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}
 
if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}
 
 
 
 
function spamcheck($field) {
  // Sanitize e-mail address
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  // Validate e-mail address
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
 
 
 
?>
 
 
<!-- place your own success html below -->
 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--Declares that this is a HTML document!-->
<title>Piccadilly CFS</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favico.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='content'>
<IMG class="header" src="../images/header.png" alt="site header">
</div>
       
 
<nav class="nav">
<hr class="hr"/>
<p class="navtext"><a href="../index.html">Home</a>
&nbsp; <a href="about_us.html">About Us</a>
&nbsp; <a href="../appliances.html">Appliances</a>
&nbsp; <a href="../photos.html">Photos</a>
&nbsp; <a href="../news.html">News</a>
&nbsp; <a href="../contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
</p>
<hr class="hr"/>
</nav>
<br><br>
<p class= "pagetitle">Form Sent!</p>
       
<p class="ptext4">
<section class="section">
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
</section>
 <div class="hr1">
<hr class="hr1">
</div>
 
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    <p class="ftext">
    <a href="credits.html">Credits </a> <br>
   &copy; Copyright Justin Bussell 2014
    </p>
</div>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the headers:

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".          <--- discards content type
           'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .     
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Try:

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
            'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using css style around the email_message as a test to see if that works. I'm pretty sure that will work. If you put  around the message, it will not work.

Also try to tell html message in the header section that it's an html message.

```
 $headers.='MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
 $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
```